# Apache NetBeans 19 Isn't Deploying to Apache Tomcat 10 Locally - Empty Folder

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

So I've just come to an older project that was created using NetBeans 8.2 (which came with Tomcat embedded as part of the NetBeans installer).

Times have moved on since then. So NetBeans is now Apache NetBeans 19, which doesn't come with Apache Tomcat embedded in the installer.

And the Apache Tomcat version that the old project was using was either Tomcat 7 or 8 from memory.

So I've managed to get both Apache NetBeans and Apache Tomcat installed. They seem to be talking to each other - although there is an issue when I try to Stop Tomcat from within Apache NetBeans which fails to work for some reason.

Anyhow. I've re-imported the NetBeans Maven web application project and pressed Play in Apache NetBeans. But when the URL opens in the web browser for the application, it's not managing to load any of the content. It manages to pick up the index.html file - although I'm honestly not sure how it is actually doing that.

When I check in the Windows Catalina/MyApp directory, it's empty. Which probably explains why when I access localhost:8080/MyApp/HelloWorldServlet, it comes back with a 404.

The URL that opens in the web browser when I compile, build and deploy the app seems to be running from this folder location, rather than Apache Tomcat, which I can't quite understand given that Apache NetBeans it set to deploy to run from the configured Apache Tomcat Server that it set up within Apache NetBeans;

C:\Users{username}\NetBeans Projects\MyApp\target\MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT

I'm not sure if there is some setup step I have missed along the way now that this new development environment has two independent apps talking to each other, rather than being bundled in a single install previously. Or if it is some permissions error, or something in the Apache NetBeans Project Settings for JDK/Java/Java EE Versions, or something in the pom.xml file that means I need to use different versions of something.

For context, this app in particular is really nothing more than a glorified HelloWorld App that connects to a DB and displays basic data. It was built as a POC. So we're not talking really complex stuff here beyond the basics of Servlet, DB, JSP, JSTL.

I've checked all log files I can find and nothing is providing me any insights into what the problem could be. I've tried playing around randomly with various configurations to see if I can spot anything that comes up as an error that could indicate where the problem lies, but not seeing anything obvious yet.

My gut feel right now is that the Apache NetBeans Project isn't managing to deploy the .war file to Apache Tomcat successfully - even though it suggests it is doing given there is a /MyApp folder in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\work\Catalina\localhost\MyApp

Any ideas what to try next to get to the bottom of this?

**Update 1 - 2023-12-10**
I've just created a brand new HelloWorldNew Maven Web Application project in Apache NetBeans in the freshly installed development environment, and it seems to work as normal. So it's either some quirky settings that the previous install of NetBeans had in the Project settings (none of which I ever touched, as it was just out of the box stuff) and/or may be related to this separate question I've just raised [Apache NetBeans 19 Cannot Stop/Start Apache Tomcat 10 Server on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77636590/apache-netbeans-19-cannot-stop-start-apache-tomcat-10-server-on-windows)

Comment: Solved via this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77636590/apache-netbeans-19-cannot-stop-start-apache-tomcat-10-server-on-windows