# Apache NetBeans 19 Cannot Stop/Start Apache Tomcat 10 Server on Windows

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

Setup;

1. Apache NetBeans 19 installed on Windows via installer
2. Apache Tomcat 10 installed on Windows via installer
3. In Apache NetBeans 19, attached a Server with the details from #2

Seems that Apache NetBeans 19 can see the contents of the Catalina Home folder from Apache Tomcat 10.

But when I right click on the Server in Apache NetBeans 19 to Start or Stop the Apache Tomcat service, it times out and just doesn't work.

These two applications are just out of the box install, so I'm sure I'm just missing a configuration step somewhere that isn't well documented from either provider.

Any ideas what this missing piece of the puzzle is?

Answer (score 0):

Installed Apache Tomcat 9.0. Added that to Apache NetBeans. Problem solved.

The only thing I can think of that I did different between installing Apache Tomcat 10 VS Apache Tomcat 9 was that I explicitly set the Shutdown Port from -1 which is the default, and basically means "don't allow anyone to shutdown Tomcat" reading the docs and setting this to 8004.

Only reason I selected 8004 is because I played with the server.xml file to change that on the Tomcat 10 setup from -1 to 8005 which tends to be the standard.

I can't see any reason why Apache Tomcat 10 doesn't play nicely here, and I can't be bothered reading poor documentation on this to try and figure it out.

This is what eventually worked for me anyhow, so my gut feel is to put it down to version incompatibility - at least on some quirky thing anyhow.

Comment: I guess this will be also related: "There is a significant breaking change between Tomcat 9.0.x and Tomcat 10.0.x. The Java package used by the specification APIs has changed from javax... to jakarta.... It will be necessary to recompile web applications against the new APIs." (https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html)